# Resizing DirectX Window Efficiently

Tags: c++, resize, directx

I am trying to find the best way to resize a graphics interface. I tried just re-initializing the device without deleting my buffers of shapes I made, but I ended up mem-leaking heavly.

I did not find anything useful on this subject.

Do I need to delete everything [buffers, devices, adapters] & restart the graphics interface from scratch?
Or is there an efficient way of doing it?

This is for a DX 10/11 interface.

**Edit:**
It is a lot of code to show, but I simply:

```
   cleanup(); // Pointers related to the device
   initDevice(hWnd); // Create new device with updated size
   draw(stuff); // I never deleted my constant/index/vertex buffers
```

To be specific, I did not delete these:

```
    ID3D11Buffer* constantBuffer;
    ID3D11Buffer* vertexBuffer;
    ID3D11Buffer* indexBuffer;
    ID3D11VertexShader* vertexShader;
    ID3D11PixelShader* pixelShader;
    ID3D11InputLayout* vertexLayout;
```

I was hoping to save performance by not recreating the graphics every moment the user is resizing.

Comment: I cannot say anything useful without viewing the code, but while reading your description  I suspect that you must reallocate some buffer instead of reuse the old ones. It happens **always** or only when you switch from a big interface to a small one?.

Comment: **Edit:** Wasnt sure what code to add, but I hope that helps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a [learn.microsoft.com article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddxgi/d3d10-graphics-programming-guide-dxgi#handling-window-resizing) which explains what you need to do. Have you read that?

Comment: /embarassed_face I didnt catch that when I Googled. Checking it out now.

Comment: Good article, but probably overkill. It would be helpful if you added what is not working for you. If you create a d3d device windowed it should really automagicaly resize. The one thing you have to do is to change the viewport and maybe your size dependent matrices. I have seen a lot of code that does manual swap chain management for no good reason.

Comment: Well, it worked easier than I was expecting. It wast too overkill when I implemented it. I noticed many lines were the same as the init step, which differed by like 3 lines. I made a function out of it, & now it works great.

Comment: @starmole : Yeah, I had to update the viewport size & the matrix ratio parameter.